# How to create connection between visual studio and linked server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-connection, linked-server

I want to connect Visual Studio with the new created linked server; but when I try to add a connection only databases under databases appear but the linked server name does not appear. How can I connect Visual Studio to my linked server in SQL Server?

My linked server's name is `CARE` and it does not appear as you can see in the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Short answer - you don't and you can't. A connection is to a specific database in a specific database engine. A linked server that is defined within that engine is not something your application "connects" to - your app can only reference it in queries if it has permissions to do so.

Comment: @SMor Yes you are correct , but in my case i have main database oracle and i created the link server to it and i will create website to do some queries and some transactions through the website some updates and inserts not all functions in the main system , so only queries allowed with link server not update and insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to any database from the list for example connect to first database you have from the list "DB_A4F558_cyanlab" , then you can use the following select statement from visual studio or stored procedure in SQL server:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([CARE] , 'SELECT * from dual');
```

In this way you can select the data you need from the linked server [CARE] through your database.

Comment: Thank you its working , but what about insert , update and delete  can i use it same way ?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this [BOL page](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) to create linked server

Should it appear in the list?

Comment: Linked server created already but its not appear and cannot connect to visual studio.